# It's 12 June 2023, almost 11 PM... location: Chitral, KPK, Pakistan. What constellations, celestial objects can you identify in this picture. Help

Tags: constellations, star-systems

[image]

This picture is taken from Chitral District of KPK, Pakistan... Time: 12 June 2023, 11PM approximately ...I want you to tell me what constellations, celestial objects can you identify in it?

Comment: I have already tried Stellarium app, and a website but couldn't find out that what part of the night sky I'm actually looking at in the given picture...

Comment: Can you add some information about equipment? Was this taken through a telescope (a small field of view) or a camera with a long or short focal length or a cell phone? Any information that helps understand the scale of the image would be helpful. Also, the location is useful but can you also add some information about the direction? Is this looking straight up, or in some direction (North, South, East, West etc.)?  *Thanks!*

Comment: Well the picture is taken through a cell phone in an area where there is almost no light pollution, it's a hilly area. I wish I knew about the direction but I don't. Sorry

Comment: I've tried Astrometry.net as well but that website couldn't help.

Comment: If you can identifying one single constellation in the picture that would be enough...

Comment: You have an incredibly good phone!

Comment: Based on the epic answer below, you could summarize this: it's a photo of Vega.  (You should now go watch *Contact* !)

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The photo shows Lyra, Cygnus, and other nearby constellations.
The diffuse glow to the right of center is the Cygnus Star Cloud, part of the Milky Way.
Here is a Stellarium rendering edited to match:

[image: Stellarium screenshot, rotated and cropped]

With hints for the field center and width, Astrometry.net found [a match](https://nova.astrometry.net/user_images/8192764#annotated) and estimated dimensions of 54°×72°.

Comment: Can you tell me what does the Colorful patch in the picture represent?

Comment: Is it star clouds?

Comment: What is the correct vocabulary for the colourful patch

Comment: @MikeG Your identification of the Cygnus Star Cloud tells us rather more about OP's equipment than he has.

Comment: guys what is the FOV across the image ?

Comment: @MikeG got it TY !